# Laravel: How to Check Redis Availability?

Tags: redis, laravel-5.4

How can i check the availability of Redis connection in **Laravel 5.4**. I tried below code, but getting an exception with ping line. How can i do, if Redis is not connected than do something else to avoid exception?

> No connection could be made because the target machine actively
>   refused it. [tcp://127.0.0.1:6379]

```
use Redis;

class SocketController extends Controller
{
    public function sendMessage(){
        $redis = Redis::connection();

        if($redis->ping()){
            print_r("expression");
        }
        else{
            print_r("expression2");
        }
    }
}
```

Also tried this:

```
$redis = Redis::connection();
        try{
            $redis->ping();
        } catch (Exception $e){
            $e->getMessage();
        }
```

But unable to catch exception

Answer (score 13):

if you are using **predis** , then it will throw `Predis\Connection\ConnectionException`

> Error while reading line from the server. [tcp://127.0.0.1:6379]  <--when redis is not connected

so catch that Exception, you will get your redis is connected or not .

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis;

    public function redis_test(Request $request){
    try{
        $redis=Redis::connect('127.0.0.1',3306);
        return response('redis working');
    }catch(\Predis\Connection\ConnectionException $e){
        return response('error connection redis');
    }
```

Comment: It's returning "redis working in every case" whatever I put the host and port

Answer (score 9):

```
<?php

namespace App\Helpers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis;

class ConnectionChecker
{
    public static function isDatabaseReady($connection = null)
    {
        $isReady = true;
        try {
            DB::connection($connection)->getPdo();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $isReady = false;
        }

        return $isReady;
    }

    public static function isRedisReady($connection = null)
    {
        $isReady = true;
        try {
            $redis = Redis::connection($connection);
            $redis->connect();
            $redis->disconnect();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $isReady = false;
        }

        return $isReady;
    }
}
```

I created a helper class to check redis and db connection

Comment: For the `$redis->connect` method I had to supply the HOST + PORT otherwise, it worked well.

Comment: There should be an associated example for the usage of this helper.

Answer (score 2):

In your constructor you can check redis status connection like this:

```
/**
 * RedisDirectGeoProximity constructor.
 * @throws RedisConnectionException
 */
public function __construct()
{
    try
    {
        $this->redisConnection = Redis::connection('default');
    }
    catch ( Exception $e )
    {
        throw new RedisConnectionException([
            'message' => trans('messages.redis.fail'),
            'code' => ApiErrorCodes::REDIS_CONNECTION_FAIL
        ]);
    }
}
```

and in your exception :

```
namespace App\Exceptions\Redis;

/**
 * Class RedisConnectionException
 * @package App\Exceptions\Redis
 */
 class RedisConnectionException extends \Exception
 {
     /**
      * RedisConnectionException constructor.
      * @param array $options
      */
      public function __construct(array $options = [])
      {
          parent::__construct($options);
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure redis is installed

```
$ sudo apt-get update 
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
$ sudo apt-get  install redis-server
```

To test that your service is functioning correctly, connect to the Redis server with the command-line client:

```
redis-cli
```

In the prompt that follows, test connectivity by typing:

```
ping
```

You should see:

Output

```
PONG
```

Install Laravel dependencies

```
composer require predis/predis
```

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-redis-on-ubuntu-16-04

https://askubuntu.com/questions/868848/how-to-install-redis-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: Yes i can do ping in redis-cli and i can also connect with redis through laravel but i don't know how to check that redis is connected or not so that i can do other stuff

Comment: Because i get exception and application stop if redis is not connected

Comment: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. [tcp://127.0.0.1:6379] means you cannot connect there from any means,

Comment: The question is another. The answer is one that does not contribute anything except saying "I know something."

Answer (score -2):

please try with `catch (\Exception $e)` incl. backslash

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.