# Laravel - Redis error when dispatching a job

Tags: laravel, laravel-queue

On one of the systems that I take care of, some times some jobs don't get dispatched due to a connection problem with Redis and this ends up returning an error to the user, on our side we can ignore this error and just miss this job, I looked for how to deal with it on Google and I didn't find anything about it.

```
public function sendMessage(Request $request, Model $model)
{
    // Do the necessary stuff
    
    ResolveMessageBilling::dispatch($model, $request->all());

    return response()->json([
        'message' => 'The message was succesfully sent'
    ], 200);
}
```

This is the error we are getting: `RedisException - socket error on read socket`

How to ignore the error if it occurs? A simple `try/catch` can resolve the issue?

```
public function sendMessage(Request $request, Model $model)
{
    // Do the necessary stuff

    try {
        ResolveMessageBilling::dispatch($model, $request->all());
    } catch(\Exception $e) {}

    return response()->json([
        'message' => 'The message was succesfully sent'
    ], 200);
}
```

Comment: Have you checked Redis connect availability? And if you are using other Redis services like `Caching with Redis`, is it working properly? [Check Redis connection availability](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45582882/12453562)

Comment: Are you using Redis from AWS, because sometimes it happens because AWS ElasticeCache Redis Cluster might using 100% of available memory

Comment: Are you using queues for the jobs? Or are they running synchronously?

Comment: @HuyPhạm Im using digitalocean memory optimized redis...

Comment: @MrEduar Yes, Im using queues...

Comment: Would I try to add Redis as a cluster and add a read-only node that would lower the rate of this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to bypass ANY error, you should use `\Throwable` instead of `\Exception`

```php
public function sendMessage(Request $request, Model $model)
{
    // Do the necessary stuff

    try {
        ResolveMessageBilling::dispatch($model, $request->all());
    } catch(\Throwable $e) {}

    return response()->json([
        'message' => 'The message was succesfully sent'
    ], 200);
}
```

see Error Hierarchy: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.errors.php7.php

If you want to bypass only the \RedisException, you should be able to use:

```php
public function sendMessage(Request $request, Model $model)
{
    // Do the necessary stuff

    try {
        ResolveMessageBilling::dispatch($model, $request->all());
    } catch(\RedisException $e) {}

    return response()->json([
        'message' => 'The message was succesfully sent'
    ], 200);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to setup Redis just want to fixed/remove errors only, follow this article: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/errors

If you want to Setup Redis(config -> detabase.php) properly, follow few step like this:

```
'redis' => [

    'client' => 'predis',

    // Keep Default as is you want to use both redis and sentinel for different service(cache, queue)'
    'default' => [
        'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
        'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
        'database' => 0,
    ],

    // Create a custom connection to use redis sentinel
    'cache_sentinel' => [
        // Set the Sentinel Host from Environment (optinal you can hardcode if want to use in prod only)
        env('CACHE_REDIS_SENTINEL_1'),
        env('CACHE_REDIS_SENTINEL_2'),
        env('CACHE_REDIS_SENTINEL_3'),
        'options' => [
            'replication' => 'sentinel',
            'service' => 'cachemaster'),
            'parameters' => [
                'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
                'database' => 0,
            ],
        ],
    ],
],
```

if you need to use Redis sentinel cache, you can create new cache connection to use the above sentinel connection like this:

```
'stores' = [

    // Default config
    'redis' => [
        'driver'     => 'redis',
        'connection' => 'default',
    ],

    // Custom cache connection(according to you)
    'sentinel_redis' => [
        'driver'     => 'redis',
        'connection' => 'cache_sentinel',
    ],
],
```

In laravel app, you can easily use via cache facade:

```
Cache::store('sentinel_redis')->get('key');
```

After configuring Redis properly, test again with the clear server cache.